# ADF- Updating Row

Tags: oracle-adf

We're trying to implement a very basic functionality in ADF 11g using Jdev(11.1.1.7). We have one table in database which is exposed to the UI layer using ADF BC. 
The requirement is to update a table when user selects one of the row. It will open a popup and then user can update the value in that dialog box. This works well but along with the current row, ADF framework is also updating the first row with the previous value of the update.

To update a row, we're using the standard commit button from the data control and then overidiing the DoDml method in EO to update additional fields.

Can someone share the details why this happening with each update and any solution for this?

Thanks,
LG

Answer (score 2):

First, remove the selectedRowKey value from the table properties otherwise this will always select first row.

After the commit refresh the page or relevant component to load updated data to UI.

If you are updating additional fields using doDML make sure to commit the data and refresh UI to load updated data.

Answer (score 0):

Commit is transaction level, if the Status of EO row is changed that row will participate in transaction. Either you need to change the status of other row to un-modify or you can override beforeCommit in VOImpl .

Thank you,
TR